# Insert into database-Moodle

Tags: php, database, moodle

I'm trying to insert data into a database but i'm getting this error even though the table exist in the database.

**Error Message**

> Table "faculty" does not exist
>
> More information about this error
>
> Debug info: 
>   Error code: ddltablenotexist
>   Stack trace:
>   line 1194 of \lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php: dml_exception thrown
>   line 19 of \local\try\process.php: call to mysqli_native_moodle_database->insert_record()

**Codes**

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

global $DB;

$name = optional_param('name', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$uni_id = optional_param('university_id', null, PARAM_TEXT);

$record1 = new stdClass();
$record1->name  = $name;
$record1->displayorder = '10000';

$record2 = new stdClass();
$record2->name = $uni_id;
$record2->displayorder = '10000';

// Insert one record at a time.
$lastinsertid1 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record1);
$lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('faculty', $record2);

?>
```

Any idea why i might be getting this? Thanks.

Comment: I notice that you refer to the current directory as `dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) ` and picked my interest. So I want to ask you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your site $CFG->prefix is set to 'mdl_' (the default), have you double-checked that the table 'mdl_faculty' exists in your database?

Comment: I haven't added any prefix to it. It's weird that it says the table doesn't exist when it obviously does.

Comment: But is the table in the database called mdl_faculty or is it called faculty? If it is called faculty (without the standard prefix), then the Moodle database functions won't find it. The prefix is there so that the database can be shared with other applications, without conflicting table names, so all tables need the prefix (and you should use the xmldb functionality to create them).

Comment: I could solve it. The problem was in the config.php. The database name was wrong.